# Android: SharedPreferences default value of a String

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I searched through a lot of questions but i didn't find one that answers my problem. So here I go :I made a custom PIN locked Activity for my App that runs as the LAUNCHER activity. This is the code I used in the onCreate() method to check if this is the first run of the app (in order to run the appropriate code and give the user the chance to set up their PIN)

```
 if (sharedPinDatabase.getString("pin", "NO PIN SAVED").equals("")) {
        Log.i("SECURITY", "NO PIN SAVED");
        tvInstructionsPin.setText(" It appers that you havent saved a PIN. Enter new PIN below.");        
    }else{}
```

But whenever I run the App for the first time (or clean all the app data) the App skips this chunk of code and goes straight to the "enter your saved PIN" part(Picture 1).I used Log.i to check what value it is given to the key ("pin") before i enter any PIN with this

```
Log.i("SECURITY", "PINs dont match Saved one is: " + sharedPinDatabase.getString("pin", "") + "entered is : " + etPinInput.getText().toString());
```

and what i get from this chunk of code is "PINs dont match Saved one **is:** entered is :"
And if i press "OK" without typing in any number (leaving the EditText blank)it works and goes to the next Activity.
Also in the settings part of the app i made this (to run at onClick)

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPrefWrite = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PIN_PREFS_DATABASE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefWrite.edit();
    editor.putString("pin", "").commit();
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LockScreen.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

And for some reason it works(when setting the value of the string to "") and gets me to the desired screen (the one that i made for the first run of the App)
this one (Picture2):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put `sharedPinDatabase.getString("pin", "NO PIN SAVED").equals("")` - if there was no PIN saved before, it will not return `""`, but it will return `"NO PIN SAVED"` (as this is default data you provided).
Just change it to `sharedPinDatabase.getString("pin", "").equals("")` - and it would work.

**Small tip** (for future).
If you use `""..equals(sharedPinDatabase.getString("pin", ""))` instead of `sharedPinDatabase.getString("pin", "").equals("")` - you will avoid NullPointerException in case when `sharedPinDatabase` is `null`.